# Regex with fswatch - Exclude files not ending with ".txt"

Tags: regex, bash, fswatch

For a list of files, I'd like to match the ones not ending with `.txt`. I am currently using this expression:

```
.*(txt$)|(html\.txt$)
```

[This expression will match everything ending in `.txt`, but I'd like it to do the opposite.](http://regex101.com/r/zA5jR3/1)

---

**Should match:**

```
happiness.html
joy.png
fear.src
```

**Should** ***not*** **match:**

```
madness.html.txt
excitement.txt
```

---

I'd like to get this so I can use it in pair with [fswatch](http://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/):

```
fswatch -0 -e 'regex here' . | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} echo "{} has been changed"
```

The problem is it doesn't seem to work.

PS: I use the tag bash instead of fswatch because I don't have enough reputation points to create it. Sorry!

Comment: Are you doing this in BASH?

Comment: I've updated my question. I'd like to use it as an argument for fswatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since question has been tagged as `bash`, lookaheads may not be supported (except `grep -P`), here is one `grep` solution that doesn't need lookaheads:

```
grep -v '\.txt$' file
happiness.html
joy.png
fear.src
```

---

**EDIT:** You can use this `xargs` command to avoid matching `*.txt` files:

```
xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} bash -c '[[ "{}" == *".txt" ]] && echo "{} has been changed"'
```

Comment: I've update my question to add more context. I'd like to use this as an argument for fswatch.

Comment: thanks a lot it seems to be working (although I've changed  !=  to == so it only matches txt files)

Comment: Sure for matching only `.txt` use `==` (edited). Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a lookbehind, like this:

```
.*$(?<!\.txt)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regex101.com/r/vO5yZ0/1)

Basically, this matches any line of text so long as the last 4 characters are not `".txt"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Negative Lookahead for this purpose.

```
^(?!.*\.txt).+$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zA5jR3/2)

You can use this expression with grep using option `-P`:

```
grep -Po '^(?!.*\.txt).+$' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what regular expression tool you are using. Many tools provide a way to invert the sense of a regex. For example:

#### bash

```
# succeeds if filename ends with .txt
[[ $filename =~ "."txt$ ]]
# succeeds if filename does not end with .txt
! [[ $filename =~ "."txt$ ]]
# another way of writing the negative
[[ ! $filename =~ "."txt$ ]]
```

#### grep

```
# succeeds if filename ends with .txt
egrep -q "\.txt$" <<<"$filename"
# succeeds if filename does not end with .txt
egrep -qv "\.txt$" <<<"$filename"
```

#### awk

```
/\.txt$/ { print "line ends with .txt" }
! /\.txt$/ { print "line doesn't end with .txt" }
$1 ~ /\.txt$/ { print "first field ends with .txt" }
$1 !~ /\.txt$/ { print "first field doesn't end with .txt" }
```

#### For the adventurous, a posix ERE which will work in any posix compatible regex engine

```
/[^t]$|[^x]t$|[^t]xt$|[^.]txt$/
```

---